# What is the correct relationship of Leads to Accounts to Organizations to Opportunities?

Tags: salesforce, one-to-many

I'm new to Salesforce but I've been given the assignment to import our data to Salesforce. In our old database, we have a lot of different information about companies and their people. In Salesforce, I see these data types:

Leads

Accounts

Organizations

Opportunities

Contacts

I assume that many of these are one-to-many relationships, but I'm not clear what the relationships are, nor does the documentation here explain:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm

Is there any place that documents the exact relationship between all the default Salesforce objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relationship per-se! The Lead object is standalone but is copied into three objects during conversion. Some fields are copied to a new Account object, some fields are copied to a Contact object and optionally some other fields are copied to an Opportunity object.
This is hard coded and not configurable for standard fields but you can define where the custom fields are going by selecting the "Map Lead Fields" button on top of the Lead's Custom Field section.

Lead standard  fields mapping:
https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/lead_conversion_mapping.htm

Salesforce Data Model:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/data_model.htm

Hope this helps! :)